# Generalizing solutions to the differential equation $y^{(n)} = y$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Question: Can you generalize to find solutions of the equation $y^{(n)} = y$?

What I have done: I know the derivative all the way to the fifth power, and what I have surmised is the further down the derivative "rabbit hole" so to speak of this differential equation, the first 2 terms are always $c_1e^x$ and $c_2e^{-x}$ with cosines and since splitting the remaining terms. But I feel that isn't the true solution, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $y^{(3)} = y$, $\displaystyle \frac{d^3(c_2e^{-x})}{dx^3} = -c_2 e^{-x} \ne c_2 e^{-x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $$y = ae^{bx} \tag{1}$$

$$y^{(n)} = ab^ne^{bx} \tag{2}$$

$$b^n = 1 \tag{3}$$

$$ b^n = e^{i2\pi k}, k \in \mathbb{Z} \tag{4}$$

$$ b_k = e^{\frac{i2\pi k}{n}}, k \in [0,n-1] \tag{5}$$

Since the equation is linear the solutions can be in superposition:

$$y = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k e^{b_kx}\tag{6}$$

Comment: Great answer, really showing the steps, can't thank you enough for sharing.

Comment: I don't like this approach. What if  we don't start with $y = ae^{bx}$? In other words, if $y$ is a general solution of $y^{(n)}=y$, how do you know that $y$ is still $\sum_k a_ke^{b_kx}$ for some $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}$?

Comment: azif00  - That's how I was taught to solve them. What other forms of $y$ could there be?

Comment: I don’t like it either, you’ve shown that the $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k e^{b_k x}$ are solutions, but not that a solution is of this form, which is tougher to prove.

Comment: Tuvasbien - Please correct me if I am wrong. I thought that the only solution to $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=y$ is $y = ae^x$. I am not aware of any other function that satisfies this equation. I may have assumed that $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}=y$ had a recursive relationship to the single derivative case. What other forms of $y$ satisfy the $n^{th}$ derivative?

Answer (score 4):

The solutions are of the form
$$ x\mapsto\sum_{\omega\in\mathbb{U}_n}a_{\omega}e^{\omega x} $$
where $a_{\omega}\in\mathbb{R}$. Indeed the maps $x\mapsto a_{\omega}e^{\omega x}$ are linearly independent, the $\omega$'s being distinct so that $\dim{\rm span}(x\mapsto e^{\omega x})_{\omega\in\mathbb{U}_n}=n$. Furthermore, the linear map $y\mapsto(y(0),\ldots,y^{(n-1)}(0))$ from the vector space $E$ of the solutions of $y^{(n)}=y$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is one-to-one according to Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, therefore $\dim E\leqslant n$. Since ${\rm span}(x\mapsto e^{\omega x})_{\omega\in\mathbb{U}_n}\subset E$ and $\dim{\rm span}(x\mapsto e^{\omega x})_{\omega\in\mathbb{U}_n}=n$, then $E={\rm span}(x\mapsto e^{\omega x})_{\omega\in\mathbb{U}_n}$.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, appreciate how in depth the answer is.